# Testing performance of parallel actions with ScalaMeter

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, executorservice, scalameter

I have used the `basic` example taken from ScalaMeter's example repository (https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter-examples). The code of the example is as follows:

```
measure method "map" in {
  using(ranges) in { r =>
    r.map(_ + 1)
  }
}
```

In my case I want to test the speedup of running some actions in parallel. A simple example could be, that I divide a range that has to be mapped. I used `ExecutorService` from `Java8` to run the tasks in parallel. It looks like this:

```
val cores = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores)

measure method "parallel map" in {
  using(ranges) in { r =>
    val tasks = (0 until cores).map { t =>
      new Callable[Unit] {
        override def call() = (0 + t until r.last by cores).map(_ + 1)
      }
    }
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    pool.invokeAll(tasks.asJava)
  }
}
```

**The problem** is that although the parallel test finishes (you can see the time results) it does not return the exit code. The implication is that if I change the `Bench.LocalTime` to `Bench.ForkedTime` even the results are gone. I am quite confused what is going on.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this was pretty trivial, because I have forgotten to `shutdown()` the pool. After adding it after `invokeAll` I have a result like below:

```
measure method "parallel map" in {
  using(ranges) in { r =>
    val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores)
    val tasks = (0 until cores).map { t =>
      new Callable[Unit] {
        override def call() = (0 + t until r.last by cores).map(_ + 1)
      }
    }
    pool.invokeAll(tasks.asJava)
    pool.shutdown()
  }
}
```

The only problem is that now, not only the action is measured but also a creation time of the `ExecutorService` and shutting it down. But I guess it won't change the results much for the time.

---

Actually after some time I have found an easier, more 'Scala' way to do the above. You can simply create a list of tasks as a list of functions to make (or can still be a list of `Callables`) and later invoke all of the tasks using `parallel` collections. Code looks as follows:

```
measure method "parallel map" in {
  using(ranges) in { r =>
    val tasks =  (0 until cores).flatMap { t =>
        (0 + t until r by cores).map(i => () => i+1)
    }
    tasks.par.map(_.apply())
  }
}
```

or even easier, because the list of tasks does not care about the `cores` now:

```
val tasks = (0 until r).map(i => () => i+1)
```